# How to include only rows where the following row is within 12 hours and rank accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, rank

We are trying to include in our SQL only those rows where the next row is within 12 hours, based on a timestamp.  Along with this, we also need to rank the rows in order to identify initial contact followed by the number of contacts within the time frame.

Unfortunately we cannot just look for min() max() within 12 hours as the date range can be longer (months) but the time between contacts can only be 12 hours. A person may have multiple contacts within the over all date range, and the initial contact has a few requirements specific to the business (see the InitialCall cte in the SQL below).

SQL used so far:

```
set nocount on;
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
set datefirst 1;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @FromDate as datetime = '2017-01-30T00:00:00';
declare @ToDate as datetime = '2017-02-05T23:59:59';
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with [InitialCalls] as 
(
    select  
        d.PatientRef,
        d.CaseRef,
        d.PathwaysStartDate as [StartDate],
        d.PathwaysFinishDate as [FinishDate]
    from dbo.[111Data] as [d]
    where d.PathwaysStartDate between @FromDate and @ToDate
        and (d.MDSSpeaktoPrimaryCareService = 1 or d.MDSContactPrimaryCareService = 1) 
        and d.PathwaysDxCode in ('Dx05','Dx06','Dx07','Dx08','Dx11','Dx110','Dx1111','Dx116','Dx117','Dx12','Dx13','Dx14','Dx15','Dx17','Dx18','Dx19','Dx20','Dx21','Dx61','Dx80','Dx85','Dx86','Dx87','Dx93','Dx93')
        and d.PathwaysFinalTriage = 1
        and d.PathwaysAbandonedTriage = 0
        and d.ReferralCategory not in ('All Services Rejected','Unsuccessful Lookup','No DoS Selected')
),
[AllCalls] as 
(
    select distinct
        count(d.CaseRef) over (partition by d.PatientRef) as [CaseVol],
        d.PatientRef,
        d.CaseRef,
        d.PathwaysStartDate as [StartDate],
        d.PathwaysFinishDate as [FinishDate]
    from dbo.[111Data] as [d]
        inner join [InitialCalls] as [ic] on ic.PatientRef = d.PatientRef
    where d.PathwaysStartDate between ic.StartDate and dateadd(hour,12, ic.StartDate)
        and d.PathwaysFinalTriage = 1
        and d.PathwaysAbandonedTriage = 0
        and d.PatientRef = 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401'
)
select 
    rank() over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.StartDate) as [Rank],
    ac.PatientRef,
    ac.CaseRef,
    ac.StartDate,
    ac.FinishDate,
    lag(ac.FinishDate) over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.FinishDate asc) as [PreviousRowFinishDate],
    datediff(hour, lag(ac.FinishDate) over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.FinishDate asc), ac.StartDate) as [HoursDifference]
from [AllCalls] as [ac]
where ac.CaseVol > 1
```

Current output:
[image: Current output]
([Link to current output](http://www.filedropper.com/socurrentoutput))

Expected output:
[image: Expected output]
([Link to expected output](http://www.filedropper.com/soexpectedoutput))

In this instance, we would like to not include the very first row (as this does not have a follow on contact within 12 hours), then rank each instance of repeat contacts. This is so we can track how many people called with a specific issue and then called up following it to chase.

**EDIT - Table Creation and altered SQL**

```
declare @table as table
(
    [CaseRef] uniqueidentifier,
    [PatientRef] uniqueidentifier,
    [StartDate] datetime,
    [FinishDate] datetime
);

insert into @table
(
    [CaseRef],
    [PatientRef],
    [StartDate],
    [FinishDate]
)
values
('DB79C49E-938C-4C40-B48E-3389D9339759', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 00:22:41', '2017-01-30 00:28:06'),
('4BFA4E3B-D313-4777-A290-3C13601D5C95', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:00:46', '2017-01-30 22:10:24'),
('F910D4DE-3CEE-4429-8844-DDE860D08192', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:25:49', '2017-01-30 22:27:58'),
('DF28DC91-02E3-47F2-88E0-397C2CBCFE41', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:44:11', '2017-01-30 22:53:22'),
('D6964286-8AE7-46AB-8DA5-88A347015C4D', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:55:17', '2017-01-30 23:01:57'),
('660B2ED7-B715-4A6C-A92B-D80267C0E4F5', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:06:16', '2017-01-30 23:08:28'),
('903AC539-4BB1-44AB-AFDB-D86C13310011', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:15:21', '2017-01-30 23:16:02'),
('75B88E5F-4795-4A21-9EA6-3B41CE958250', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:28:31', '2017-01-30 23:29:53'),
('DD6A4BD5-EF75-44CE-9309-4C14B2A21FF4', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:45:42', '2017-01-30 23:46:13'),
('518319BA-0EDE-46D8-B0B7-E8CEB233DEDF', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:54:02', '2017-01-31 00:03:13'),
('FB5A5A54-E580-40F2-94FD-64E20EA5C4DD', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-31 16:13:01', '2017-01-31 16:21:02'),
('8A4FD0C3-59BF-43AB-A829-F2396D6FB26A', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-31 18:26:14', '2017-01-31 18:39:20'),
('8CB94AF1-9664-4081-A2E1-271ED16B147B', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-01 08:10:41', '2017-02-01 08:18:18'),
('0DC6B68B-0458-48DF-B286-C1A978653981', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-01 15:40:45', '2017-02-01 15:48:24'),
('DB239857-6870-4AD9-8149-69ED6151CCB2', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 16:54:40', '2017-02-02 17:10:27'),
('938CCFF4-66C9-48B1-BDB7-D9144D2BD522', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 19:29:18', '2017-02-02 19:30:14'),
('1EC730D0-AF85-45BF-BD06-12B23124151F', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 19:43:28', '2017-02-02 19:47:12');

set nocount on;
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
set datefirst 1;
with [InitialCalls] as 
(
    select  
        t.PatientRef,
        t.CaseRef,
        t.StartDate,
        t.FinishDate
    from @table as [t]
),
[AllCalls] as 
(
    select distinct
        count(t.CaseRef) over (partition by t.PatientRef) as [CaseVol],
        t.PatientRef,
        t.CaseRef,
        t.StartDate,
        t.FinishDate
    from @table as [t]
        inner join [InitialCalls] as [ic] on ic.PatientRef = t.PatientRef
    where t.StartDate between ic.StartDate and dateadd(hour,12, ic.StartDate)
)
select 
    rank() over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.StartDate) as [Rank],
    ac.PatientRef,
    ac.CaseRef,
    ac.StartDate,
    ac.FinishDate,
    lag(ac.FinishDate) over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.FinishDate asc) as [PreviousRowFinishDate],
    datediff(hour, lag(ac.FinishDate) over (partition by ac.PatientRef order by ac.FinishDate asc), ac.StartDate) as [HoursDifference]
from [AllCalls] as [ac]
where ac.CaseVol > 1;
```

**Final Edit - Answer with lots of help from Vladimir**

```
set nocount on;
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
set datefirst 1;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @FromDate as datetime = '2017-01-30T00:00:00';
declare @ToDate as datetime = '2017-02-05T23:59:59';
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

with [InitialCalls] as
(
    select  
        d.PatientRef,
        d.CaseRef,
        d.PathwaysStartDate,
        d.PathwaysFinishDate,
        d.PathwaysDxCode
    from dbo.[111Data] as [d]
    where d.PathwaysStartDate between @FromDate and @ToDate
        and (d.MDSSpeaktoPrimaryCareService = 1 or d.MDSContactPrimaryCareService = 1) 
        and d.PathwaysDxCode in ('Dx05','Dx06','Dx07','Dx08','Dx11','Dx110','Dx1111','Dx116','Dx117','Dx12','Dx13','Dx14','Dx15','Dx17','Dx18','Dx19','Dx20','Dx21','Dx61','Dx80','Dx85','Dx86','Dx87','Dx93','Dx93')
        and d.PathwaysFinalTriage = 1
        and d.PathwaysAbandonedTriage = 0
        and d.ReferralCategory not in ('All Services Rejected','Unsuccessful Lookup','No DoS Selected')
),
[AllCalls] as 
(
    select 
        d.PatientRef,
        d.CaseRef,
        d.CaseNumber,
        d.PathwaysStartDate,
        d.PathwaysFinishDate,
        isnull(lag(d.PathwaysStartDate) over (partition by d.PatientRef order by d.PathwaysStartDate), '1900-01-01') as [PreviousStartDate]
    from dbo.[111Data] as [d]
        inner join [InitialCalls] as [ic] on ic.PatientRef = d.PatientRef
    where d.PathwaysStartDate between ic.PathwaysStartDate and dateadd(hour,12, ic.PathwaysStartDate)
        and d.PathwaysFinalTriage = 1
        and d.PathwaysAbandonedTriage = 0
),
[InitialCallsMarkers] as
(
    select
        ic.PatientRef,
        ic.CaseRef,
        ic.CaseNumber,
        ic.PathwaysStartDate,
        ic.PathwaysFinishDate,
        iif(datediff(hour, ic.PreviousStartDate, ic.PathwaysStartDate) >= 12, 1, 0) as [Marker]
    from [AllCalls] as [ic]
),
[InitialCallsSequences] as
(
    select distinct
        icm.PatientRef,
        icm.CaseRef,
        icm.CaseNumber,
        icm.PathwaysStartDate,
        icm.PathwaysFinishDate,
        icm.Marker,
        sum(icm.Marker) over (partition by icm.PatientRef order by icm.PathwaysStartDate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as [SequenceNumber]
    from [InitialCallsMarkers] as [icm]
),
[InitialCallsRanks] as
(
    select 
        ics.PatientRef,
        ics.CaseRef,
        ics.CaseNumber,
        ics.PathwaysStartDate,
        ics.PathwaysFinishDate,
        ics.SequenceNumber,
        ics.Marker,
        row_number() over (partition by ics.PatientRef, ics.SequenceNumber order by ics.PathwaysStartDate) as [Rank],
        count(*) over (partition by ics.PatientRef, ics.SequenceNumber) as [SequenceLength]
    from [InitialCallsSequences] as [ics]
)
select
    icr.[Rank],
    icr.PatientRef,
    icr.CaseRef,
    icr.CaseNumber,
    icr.PathwaysStartDate,
    icr.PathwaysFinishDate,
    icr.Marker,
    icr.SequenceNumber,
    icr.SequenceLength
from [InitialCallsRanks] as [icr]
where icr.SequenceLength > 1
order by icr.PatientRef, icr.PathwaysStartDate;
```

Comment: with questions like this it's useful to simplify your data/problem to an example that people can quickly use to replicate your problem and provide a solution. it seems there are a lot of extra columns and values in the mix here that may not relate to your underlying problem that will make it more difficult for people answering.

Comment: also if you can ever provide create table scripts, maybe to populate some representative sample temporary tables, and drop some data in them, that can be useful

Comment: I've edited the question to include the table creation, data, and the version of the script that uses this without the additional table specific filtering.

Comment: I've added a tag for the version of SQL Server based on the fact that you use `LAG` function. It was added in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
declare @table as table
(
    [CaseRef] uniqueidentifier,
    [PatientRef] uniqueidentifier,
    [StartDate] datetime,
    [FinishDate] datetime
);

insert into @table
(
    [CaseRef],
    [PatientRef],
    [StartDate],
    [FinishDate]
)
values
('DB79C49E-938C-4C40-B48E-3389D9339759', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 00:22:41', '2017-01-30 00:28:06'),
('4BFA4E3B-D313-4777-A290-3C13601D5C95', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:00:46', '2017-01-30 22:10:24'),
('F910D4DE-3CEE-4429-8844-DDE860D08192', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:25:49', '2017-01-30 22:27:58'),
('DF28DC91-02E3-47F2-88E0-397C2CBCFE41', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:44:11', '2017-01-30 22:53:22'),
('D6964286-8AE7-46AB-8DA5-88A347015C4D', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 22:55:17', '2017-01-30 23:01:57'),
('660B2ED7-B715-4A6C-A92B-D80267C0E4F5', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:06:16', '2017-01-30 23:08:28'),
('903AC539-4BB1-44AB-AFDB-D86C13310011', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:15:21', '2017-01-30 23:16:02'),
('75B88E5F-4795-4A21-9EA6-3B41CE958250', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:28:31', '2017-01-30 23:29:53'),
('DD6A4BD5-EF75-44CE-9309-4C14B2A21FF4', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:45:42', '2017-01-30 23:46:13'),
('518319BA-0EDE-46D8-B0B7-E8CEB233DEDF', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-30 23:54:02', '2017-01-31 00:03:13'),
('FB5A5A54-E580-40F2-94FD-64E20EA5C4DD', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-31 16:13:01', '2017-01-31 16:21:02'),
('8A4FD0C3-59BF-43AB-A829-F2396D6FB26A', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-01-31 18:26:14', '2017-01-31 18:39:20'),
('8CB94AF1-9664-4081-A2E1-271ED16B147B', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-01 08:10:41', '2017-02-01 08:18:18'),
('0DC6B68B-0458-48DF-B286-C1A978653981', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-01 15:40:45', '2017-02-01 15:48:24'),
('DB239857-6870-4AD9-8149-69ED6151CCB2', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 16:54:40', '2017-02-02 17:10:27'),
('938CCFF4-66C9-48B1-BDB7-D9144D2BD522', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 19:29:18', '2017-02-02 19:30:14'),
('1EC730D0-AF85-45BF-BD06-12B23124151F', 'A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401', '2017-02-02 19:43:28', '2017-02-02 19:47:12');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Prev
AS
(
    SELECT
        CaseRef
        ,PatientRef
        ,StartDate
        ,FinishDate
        ,ISNULL(LAG(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientRef ORDER BY StartDate),
            '2000-01-01') AS PrevStart
    FROM @Table AS T
)
,CTE_Markers
AS
(
    SELECT
        CaseRef
        ,PatientRef
        ,StartDate
        ,FinishDate
        ,PrevStart
        ,CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(hour, PrevStart, StartDate) >= 12) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GapIsLargeMarker
    FROM CTE_Prev
)
,CTE_Sequences
AS
(
    SELECT
        CaseRef
        ,PatientRef
        ,StartDate
        ,FinishDate
        ,PrevStart
        ,GapIsLargeMarker
        ,SUM(GapIsLargeMarker) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientRef ORDER BY StartDate 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SeqNumber
    FROM CTE_Markers
)
,CTE_Ranks
AS
(
    SELECT
        CaseRef
        ,PatientRef
        ,StartDate
        ,FinishDate
        ,PrevStart
        ,GapIsLargeMarker
        ,SeqNumber
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientRef,SeqNumber ORDER BY StartDate) AS rnk
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientRef, SeqNumber) AS SeqLength
    FROM CTE_Sequences
)
SELECT
    CaseRef
    ,PatientRef
    ,StartDate
    ,FinishDate
    ,PrevStart
    ,GapIsLargeMarker
    ,SeqNumber
    ,rnk
    ,SeqLength
FROM CTE_Ranks
WHERE SeqLength > 1
ORDER BY PatientRef, StartDate;
```

**Result**

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----------+
|               CaseRef                |              PatientRef              |        StartDate        |       FinishDate        |        PrevStart        | GapIsLargeMarker | SeqNumber | rnk | SeqLength |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| 4BFA4E3B-D313-4777-A290-3C13601D5C95 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 22:00:46.000 | 2017-01-30 22:10:24.000 | 2017-01-30 00:22:41.000 |                1 |         2 |   1 |         9 |
| F910D4DE-3CEE-4429-8844-DDE860D08192 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 22:25:49.000 | 2017-01-30 22:27:58.000 | 2017-01-30 22:00:46.000 |                0 |         2 |   2 |         9 |
| DF28DC91-02E3-47F2-88E0-397C2CBCFE41 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 22:44:11.000 | 2017-01-30 22:53:22.000 | 2017-01-30 22:25:49.000 |                0 |         2 |   3 |         9 |
| D6964286-8AE7-46AB-8DA5-88A347015C4D | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 22:55:17.000 | 2017-01-30 23:01:57.000 | 2017-01-30 22:44:11.000 |                0 |         2 |   4 |         9 |
| 660B2ED7-B715-4A6C-A92B-D80267C0E4F5 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 23:06:16.000 | 2017-01-30 23:08:28.000 | 2017-01-30 22:55:17.000 |                0 |         2 |   5 |         9 |
| 903AC539-4BB1-44AB-AFDB-D86C13310011 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 23:15:21.000 | 2017-01-30 23:16:02.000 | 2017-01-30 23:06:16.000 |                0 |         2 |   6 |         9 |
| 75B88E5F-4795-4A21-9EA6-3B41CE958250 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 23:28:31.000 | 2017-01-30 23:29:53.000 | 2017-01-30 23:15:21.000 |                0 |         2 |   7 |         9 |
| DD6A4BD5-EF75-44CE-9309-4C14B2A21FF4 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 23:45:42.000 | 2017-01-30 23:46:13.000 | 2017-01-30 23:28:31.000 |                0 |         2 |   8 |         9 |
| 518319BA-0EDE-46D8-B0B7-E8CEB233DEDF | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-30 23:54:02.000 | 2017-01-31 00:03:13.000 | 2017-01-30 23:45:42.000 |                0 |         2 |   9 |         9 |
| FB5A5A54-E580-40F2-94FD-64E20EA5C4DD | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-31 16:13:01.000 | 2017-01-31 16:21:02.000 | 2017-01-30 23:54:02.000 |                1 |         3 |   1 |         2 |
| 8A4FD0C3-59BF-43AB-A829-F2396D6FB26A | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-01-31 18:26:14.000 | 2017-01-31 18:39:20.000 | 2017-01-31 16:13:01.000 |                0 |         3 |   2 |         2 |
| 8CB94AF1-9664-4081-A2E1-271ED16B147B | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-02-01 08:10:41.000 | 2017-02-01 08:18:18.000 | 2017-01-31 18:26:14.000 |                1 |         4 |   1 |         2 |
| 0DC6B68B-0458-48DF-B286-C1A978653981 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-02-01 15:40:45.000 | 2017-02-01 15:48:24.000 | 2017-02-01 08:10:41.000 |                0 |         4 |   2 |         2 |
| DB239857-6870-4AD9-8149-69ED6151CCB2 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-02-02 16:54:40.000 | 2017-02-02 17:10:27.000 | 2017-02-01 15:40:45.000 |                1 |         5 |   1 |         3 |
| 938CCFF4-66C9-48B1-BDB7-D9144D2BD522 | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-02-02 19:29:18.000 | 2017-02-02 19:30:14.000 | 2017-02-02 16:54:40.000 |                0 |         5 |   2 |         3 |
| 1EC730D0-AF85-45BF-BD06-12B23124151F | A3E14866-4DD5-4001-AF63-21819F49B401 | 2017-02-02 19:43:28.000 | 2017-02-02 19:47:12.000 | 2017-02-02 19:29:18.000 |                0 |         5 |   3 |         3 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

Run the query step-by-step, cte-by-cte and examine intermediary results to understand how it works.

`CTE_Prev` returns `PrevStart` from the previous row. If it is the first row for a patient it is `NULL`, so I set it to a constant `2001-01-01`.

`CTE_Markers` returns `GapIsLargeMarker` set to 1 if the gap between two rows is more than 12 hours. It marks with `1` those rows where a new "sequence" starts.

`CTE_Sequences` fills the sequence numbers `SeqNumber` using running total.

`CTE_Ranks` calculates row numbers (`rnk`) within each sequence and how many rows (`SeqLength`) are in each sequence.

Finally, we return only those sequences that have more than 1 row in them.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked with some very minor tweaks.  I've edited the question to include the final version we're using.

Answer (score 0):

in general you could do

```
...WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[111Data] as [d2] 
                                  WHERE D2.StartDate BETWEEN 
                                        D1.StartDate 
                                        AND DATEADD(hour, 12, D1.StartDate)
                )
```

to select such a record with a record following it within 12 hours - have you tried anything like that?

I'm not sure what you mean by the second part regarding ranking and counting within the time frame  You could probably accomplish it using a sub-query

sorry I made a mistake, you need to exclude the record under scrutiny from the EXISTS

```
...WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[111Data] as [d2] 
                              WHERE D2.StartDate >
                                    D1.StartDate 
                                    AND D2.StartDate <= DATEADD(hour, 12, D1.StartDate)
            )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it appears to give the same results as the existing SQL.

Comment: I wasn't thinking, you need to exclude the record under scrutiny from that, either by excluding a unique key, or using > time

Comment: This is where I got to. However, that that excludes the rank 1 for the other instances - I either have the incorrectly included line at the top, or I am missing the first two lines. I need to exclude CaseRef DB79C49E-938C-4C40-B48E-3389D9339759 and keep 4BFA4E3B-D313-4777-A290-3C13601D5C95

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'losing rank 1' - the concept of the ranking you need isn't clear to me - if you had 00:00, 12:10, 12:45, 15:00 - then you would want to exclude the 00:00, but what ranks would the 3 displayed rows have?

Comment: If you look at the expected output, I need to lose row 1 and keep row 2. Your option is one that I have considered already, but that loses row 1 and 2.  "Rank 1" refers to the fact that each initial contact should be rank 1 in the desired output, but are filtered out by this solution.

Comment: Perhaps I'm implementing it wrong - I've changed the `[AllCalls]` section in the edited version to: 
`[AllCalls] as 
(
 select distinct
  count(t.CaseRef) over (partition by t.PatientRef) as [CaseVol],
  t.PatientRef,
  t.CaseRef,
  t.StartDate,
  t.FinishDate
 from @table as [t]
  --inner join [InitialCalls] as [ic] on ic.PatientRef = t.PatientRef
 where exists 
  (
   select 1
   from [InitialCalls] as [ic] 
   where t.StartDate > ic.StartDate 
    and t.StartDate <= dateadd(hour,12, ic.StartDate)
  )
)`

Comment: row 1 doesn't have a matching record within 12 hours of it, but row 2 does.  you should be able to use EXISTS to find that row 2 does have a matching record in the next 12 hours