# How to remove rest of the ordered rows with the same ID after the first row which occurs more than once with that ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have the following structure for the table `DataTable`: every column is of the datatype int, `RowID` is an identity column and the primary key. `LinkID` is a foreign key and links to rows of an other table.

```
RowID   LinkID   Order  Data    DataSpecifier
1       120      1      1       1
2       120      2      1       3
3       120      3      1       10
4       120      4      1       13
5       120      5      1       10
6       120      6      1       13
7       371      1      6       2
8       371      2      3       5
9       371      3      8       1
10      371      4      10      1
11      371      5      7       2
12      371      6      3       3
13      371      7      7       2
14      371      8      17      4
.................................
.................................
```

I'm trying to do a query which alters every `LinkID` batch in the following way:

- Take every row with same `LinkID` (e.g. the first batch is the first 6 rows here)
- Order them by the `Order` column
- Look at `Data` and `DataSpecifier` columns as one compare unit (They can be thought as one column, called `dataunit`):
- Keep as many rows from `Order=1` onwards, until a `dataunit` comes by which appears more than one time in the batch
- Keep that final row, but delete rest of the rows with same `LinkID` and greater `Order` value

So for the `LinkID` `120`:

- Sort the batch by the `Order` column (already sorted here, but should still do it)
- Start looking from the top (So `Order=1` here), go as long as you don't see a value which appears more than 1 time in the batch
- Stop at the first duplicate `Order=3` (`dataunit` `1 10` is also on `Order` `5`).
- Delete everything which has the `LinkID=120 AND Order>=4`

After similar process for `LinkID` `371` (and every other `LinkID` in the table), the processed table will look like this:

```
RowID   LinkID   Order  Data    DataSpecifier
1       120      1      1       1
2       120      2      1       3
3       120      3      1       10
7       371      1      6       2
8       371      2      3       5
9       371      3      8       1
10      371      4      10      1
11      371      5      7       2
.................................
.................................
```

I've never done an SQL query which this complicated. I know the query has to be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM DataTable  
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID
                FROM DataTable
                WHERE -- ?
                GROUP BY LinkID
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- ?
                ORDER BY [Order]);
```

but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this and get the query right. I would preferably do this in pure SQL, with one executable (and reusable) query.

---

I asked a very similar question here: [How to remove rest of the rows with the same ID starting from the first duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041788/how-to-remove-rest-of-the-rows-with-the-same-id-starting-from-the-first-duplicate)

But since I realized that my original filtering logic in the question was not actually what I needed and that question had already been answered correctly, I had to make this new question.

Comment: I think you may be able to use the answer provided on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133711/how-to-include-only-rows-where-the-following-row-is-within-12-hours-and-rank-acc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, my previous solution updated. A few `GROUP BY` should be enough. Code is simple enough to be understood by reading.

**Set up:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #YourData

CREATE TABLE #YourData (
    RowID INT,
    LinkID INT,
    [Order] INT,
    Data INT,
    DataSpecifier INT)

INSERT INTO #YourData (
    RowID,
    LinkID,
    [Order],
    Data,
    DataSpecifier)
VALUES
    ('1', ' 120', '1', '1', ' 1'), 
    ('2', ' 120', '2', '1', ' 3'), 
    ('3', ' 120', '3', '1', ' 10'), 
    ('4', ' 120', '4', '1', ' 13'), 
    ('5', ' 120', '5', '1', ' 10'), 
    ('6', ' 120', '6', '1', ' 13'), 

    ('7', ' 371', '1', '6', ' 2'), 
    ('8', ' 371', '2', '3', ' 5'), 
    ('9', ' 371', '3', '8', ' 1'), 
    ('10', '371', '4', '10', '1'), 
    ('11', '371', '5', '7', ' 2'), 
    ('12', '371', '6', '3', ' 3'), 
    ('13', '371', '7', '7', ' 2'), 
    ('14', '371', '8', '17', '4')
```

**Solution:**

```
;WITH DuplicatesByLinkID AS
(
    SELECT
        Y.LinkID,
        Y.Data,
        Y.DataSpecifier,
        [Order] = MIN([Order])
    FROM
        #YourData AS Y
    GROUP BY
        Y.LinkID,
        Y.Data,
        Y.DataSpecifier
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1
),
FirstDuplicateByLinkID AS
(
    SELECT
        D.LinkID,
        MinOrder = MIN(D.[Order])
    FROM
        DuplicatesByLinkID AS D
    GROUP BY
        D.LinkID
)
DELETE Y FROM
    #YourData AS Y
    INNER JOIN FirstDuplicateByLinkID AS M ON
        Y.LinkID = M.LinkID AND
        Y.[Order] > M.MinOrder

SELECT * FROM #YourData
```

**Result:**

```
RowID   LinkID  Order   Data    DataSpecifier
1       120     1       1       1
2       120     2       1       3
3       120     3       1       10
7       371     1       6       2
8       371     2       3       5
9       371     3       8       1
10      371     4       10      1
11      371     5       7       2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and was extremely easy to modify to work with my actual column and table names :)